# Who/What am I? (The Five Ws)

Tags: riddle

> I'm what stands between your family.
>   I'm when your mind is set.
>   I'm where your journey starts and ends.
>   I'm why your story comes to life.

Hint:

> For the last time, my brother is not in a coma.

Comment: There are `seemingly` grammatical errors present: "stand" instead of "stands", "start" and "end" instead of "Starts" and "ends", "come" instead of "comes". Are these intentional?

Comment: oh i'm not fluent in English. sr it's not intentional

Comment: So is your brother in a semi-colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some feedback from the OP that first answer was close, here's my 2nd shot.

**Attempt #2**

> You are the period.

I'm what stands between your family.

> In the periodic table of elements, the members of a family (vertical columns) are separated into different **periods** (horizontal rows).

I'm when your mind is set.

> Saying **"Period [ . ]"** after a statement often means the matter is set in stone.

I'm where your journey starts and ends.

> In physics, a **period** is defined as the duration of time of one cycle in a repeating event. Hence, it marks both the start and end of a cycle.

I'm why your story comes to life.

> In film / television, **period** is a descriptor used for works set some time in the past (ie, historical period drama).

---

**Attempt #1**

> You are the punctuation mark(s)

I'm what stands between your family.

> If you list your family members (or any list of *related* words), the **comma [ , ]** will likely be between each of those names.

I'm when your mind is set.

> Saying **"Period [ . ]"** after a statement often means the matter is set in stone.

I'm where your journey starts and ends.

> Epic travels are filled with **questions [ ? ]** at the beginning with the **answers [ . ]** at the end.

I'm why your story comes to life.

> The **exclamation mark [ ! ]** brings life to any sentence.

Comment: Wow, rot13(Jryc lbh jnf pybfr, vg'f n chapghngvba znex.
Pna lbh thrff jung vg vf?). How did you came up with your answer?

Comment: The hint suggested what it was. But I couldn't decide which one specifically since I can't find one which satisfied all the clues / lines in the riddle. Let me think about it some more.

Comment: @Sinh I've updated my answer. I think this one hits most, if not all, of the clues.

Comment: You got the answer right.

Comment: @Sinh Yay! You can choose to accept an answer by clicking the check mark right below the upvote / downvote buttons. It awards points to the answer and marks your question as solved too. I noticed you're new here so I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Typing on phone is hard. To clarify some hint:
1. I was referring to the way of accessing member of a struct.
3. It can be use as a symbol for root in a relative path, & the end of a sentence.
4. A long stretch I admit, think about how your paragraph be if there's no punctuation.